# Magento 2 : How to change the quantity of items in the checkout?

Tags: magento2, checkout, frontend

How to change the quantity of cart items in the checkout? I have a select that should display the quantity of items in the cart. When changing the value, change the quantity of goods in the basket and recalculate the total amount of the order.

File: Magento_Checkout/web/template/summary/item/details.html

```
<select 
   data-bind="options: qtyOptions, value: selectedQty, event: {change: updateQty($parent)}"
   class="cart-item__select js-cart-qty"
>
</select>
```

module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/item/details.js

```
updateQty: function(item) {
        var data = {
            item_id: item.item_id,
            item_qty: this.selectedQty()
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: url.build('checkout/cart/updateItemQty'),
            data: data,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            context: this,
        }).done(function (response) {
                alert('hey! you updated successfully, checkout cart.')
                console.log(response)
            })
            .fail(function (error) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }
```

[image]

Comment: This would help you 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261359/how-to-delete-the-item-from-cart-in-checkout

Comment: It did not help

Comment: What you've tried?

Comment: Have you created selectedQty() function in JS?

Comment: yes,  selectedQty: ko.observable(1)